# Addition of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, arithmetic

Prove or provide a counterexample

Let $V_1, V_2, W$ be subspaces of the vector space $V$, such that $V_1+W=V_2+W$

Then can we conclude that $V_1=V_2$?

Comment: What if $V=\Bbb R^2$, and $V_1,V_2$, and $W$ are distinct one-dimensional subspaces of $V$?

Comment: or $V_2=\mathbb R^2$?

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried? Think about the spaces $V_1$ spanned by $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ and $V_2$ spanned by $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$. Consider $W$ spanned by $(0,1,1)$.

Then $V_1 + W = V_2 + W = \mathbb{R}^3$. Are $V_1$ and $V_2$ equal as vector subspaces?

Comment: That should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @RobArthan Why do you think so? It provides a direct counter-example which is what is being asked for.

Comment: Because you asked "what have you tried?"?

Comment: @RobArthan: Obviously *What have you tried?* would be inappropriate as the entirety of an answer, but including it in a genuine answer equally obviously does not invalidate that answer. It might even serve as a gentle hint/reminder, should the OP ask other questions in the future.